# Detect Date Input change and Dynamically disabling button using Javascript but button still enabled

Tags: javascript

I would like to disable a button dynamically if a user hasn't entered details in any input field in a form.

This is what I have tried:

```
<div id="create-container">
    <form  method="post" onkeyup="btnActivation()">  
        <h1>Create Transaction</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="created">Created:</label>
            <input type="date" id="created" name="created" placeholder="Transaction Created">
            <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
            <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Enter amount"> 
            <label for="merchant">Merchant:</label>
            <input type="text" id="merchant" name="merchant" placeholder="Enter Merchant">          
        </fieldset>
        <button id="create-transaction" class="create-button" type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function btnActivation() {
    if(!document.getElementById('created').value.length ||
        !document.getElementById('merchant').value.length ||
        !document.getElementById('amount').value.length
    ) {
        document.getElementById('create-transaction').disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('create-transaction').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why my button is not disabled

Comment: Your onkyeup doesnt run until the next input is updated. So for example when someone enters a value for amount - thats when the created value shows not null - why dont you just add a event listener to the button (without it being disabled) and on click check if fields are empty or not - and also add the required attribute to the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To detect Date input change use onchange event listener in form**

```js
function btnActivation() {

    if (
      !document.getElementById("created").value.length ||
      !document.getElementById("merchant").value.length ||
      !document.getElementById("amount").value.length
    ) {
      document.getElementById("create-transaction").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("create-transaction").disabled = false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="create-container">
  <form method="post" onkeyup="btnActivation()" onchange="btnActivation()">
    <h1>Create Transaction</h1>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="created">Created:</label>
      <input
        type="date"
        id="created"
        name="created"
        placeholder="Transaction Created"
      />
      <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="amount"
        name="amount"
        placeholder="Enter amount"
      />
      <label for="merchant">Merchant:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="merchant"
        name="merchant"
        placeholder="Enter Merchant"
      />
    </fieldset>
    <button
      id="create-transaction"
      class="create-button"
      type="submit"
      disabled
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```